# Not able to see results from trained huggingface model

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, large-language-model

I'm new to huggingface and after reading the documentation, I've been trying to fine-tune DNABERT2 on my simple dataset.

Basically, the idea is I have some DNA sequences that are labeled as '1' or '0', and I want to use the pre-trained DNABERT2 model to predict the label.

Example:

```
AATTGGC    1
TCTC       0 
TGTTA      1
```

I pretty much have all of the steps down, I think-- but I'm running into an error at the very last line-- `TypeError: '_TensorSliceDataset' object is not subscriptable`.

Here is all of the code I used (derived the steps from here: https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/transformers_doc/en/training.ipynb):

```
import pandas as pd
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("zhihan1996/DNABERT-2-117M", trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("zhihan1996/DNABERT-2-117M", trust_remote_code=True).to('cuda')

# Assuming 'sequences' is a list of DNA sequences and 'labels' is a list of binary labels (0 or 1)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
df = pd.read_csv('/content/dev.csv', nrows=10)
df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/test.csv', nrows=10)

train_sequences=df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
test_sequences=df1.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
train_labels=df.iloc[:, 1].tolist()
test_labels =df1.iloc[:, 1].tolist()

# Tokenize and format the data
train_encodings = tokenizer(train_sequences, truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(test_sequences, truncation=True, padding=True)

# convert encodings

import tensorflow as tf

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_encodings),
    train_labels
))

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(test_encodings),
    test_labels
))


from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")



import numpy as np
import evaluate

metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")


def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)



from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

Everything runs fine until I run the final line:

```
trainer.train()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your case. The model you are trying to fine-tune for classification is a fill-mask model. You can use this [course chapter](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/3) to understand how to fine-tune such a model for classification tasks. Or you can further fine-tune a fine-tuned version of the same model for classification such as this [one](https://huggingface.co/tydymy/DNABERT-2-117M-finetuned-human-150bp-dna-classification). For the second case you cannot pass a tensorflow Dataset to the Trainer function. Your `train_dataset` and `test_dataset` need to be replaced with this

```
class IMDbDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

train_dataset = IMDbDataset(train_encodings, train_labels)
# val_dataset = IMDbDataset(val_encodings, val_labels)
test_dataset = IMDbDataset(test_encodings, test_labels)
```

Check this [link](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.1.0/custom_datasets.html) to understand it better